# Can someone help me to evaluate this integral:

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can someone help me with evaluating this integral:

$$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{2x^2-1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx$$

I tried using integration by parts, integration by substitution....but nothing...

Comment: $\dfrac u{\sqrt{u}} = \sqrt{u}$ when $u\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\int\frac{2x^2-1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx = x\sqrt{x^2-1}+C$$ thus $$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{2x^2-1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx=2\sqrt{4-1}-1\sqrt{1-1}\\=2\sqrt3$$
You can substitute $x^2-1=z$ to get $$\int\frac{2x^2-1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx \\= \frac12\int\frac{2z+1} {\sqrt{z}}\, dz \\= \frac12\left(\int \sqrt{z}\, dz+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\, dz\right)\\=\frac13\sqrt{z^3}+\sqrt{z}+C=\sqrt{z}\left(\frac{z}{3}+1\right)+C$$
So, making the final passage
$$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{2x^2-1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx \\= \int_{0}^{3} \frac12\int\frac{2z+1} {\sqrt{z}}\, dz\\=\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{3}{3}+1\right)-\sqrt{0}\left(\frac{0}{3}+1\right)=2\sqrt3$$

Comment: It's correct but how did you get it?

Comment: Well, once you get used to "see" derivative of the functions, sometimes it's easy to solve integrals..moreover I did it a similar one yesterday ;)

Comment: suppose that i can't find the primitive integral, so how should I go on?

Comment: You can substitute $x^2-1=z$ to get $$\int\frac{2x^2-1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}}\, dx \\= \int\frac{2z+1} {\sqrt{z}}\, dz \\= 2\int \sqrt{z}\, dz+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\, dz\\=\frac43\sqrt{z^3}+2\sqrt{z}$$

Comment: Well i get $6\sqrt{3}$...

Comment: notice that $dz=2xdx$

Comment: sorry..I mistyped...but now, I can't correct ;(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14217/discussion-between-i-love-math-and-foga)

Comment: Foga i can't type in chat...why?

Comment: I don't know, but I'll edit the answer...

Comment: it's still wrong...

Comment: ...hm I edited.

Comment: ok now it's correct...XD

Comment: LOL, sorry, but I've answered with a different keyboard (previous broke down), and in addition to get used to *Integral Formula*, I have to type well with the new keyboard...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Another useful subsitution that simplifies integrals with $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is $x = \cosh u$. You then use the identities $\cosh^2 - 1 = \sinh^2$ and $\cosh' = \sinh$.

Comment: and also $2\cosh^2u-1=\cosh2u$. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
Start with [Trigonometric Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)  $$x=\sec\theta$$

to get $$I=\int_0^{\frac\pi3}(2\sec^2\theta-1)\frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta}{\tan\theta}=\int_0^{\frac\pi3}(2\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta)\ d\theta$$

Then use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{2(x^2-1)+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=2\sqrt{x^2-1}+\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Now use $\#1,\#8$  formulae of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html)

Comment: I can't use #8...notice that i have -1 under square root

Comment: @ILoveMath, Replace $a^2$ with $-b^2$